# Where - хотя бы один null (TransactSql)

Tags: sql-server

Вопрос простой. Как в условии Where выбрать те строки, в которых хотя бы один атрибут IS NULL? Есть способ сделать это, не перечисляя все атрибуты?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...?
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так то и звездочку не очень хороший стиль ставить, лучше в SELECT все нужные поля перечислить.
[Ссылка на аналогичный вопрос на нерусской версии сайта.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488859/find-all-rows-with-null-values-in-any-column)
Если коротко и сложности с языком: перечисляйте руками, это вообще не проблема. SQL довольно объемный язык, чего экономить лениться то.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно, то решения из коробки в MS SQL для данной задачи нет. Можно извратиться и создать самописную функцию, принимающую имя таблицы и Id строки, что бы по этим данным можно было что-то динамическое сгенерить на основе схемы таблицы и вернуть TRUE/FALSE. Потом эту функцию дёргать в WHERE. Решение будет явно корявым и медленным, но это уже другая история...